# Issue with MSSQL Data retrieving

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with 1 million record but when I am trying to find one record with id which is guid a unique identifier then it takes 3 minutes. This column has clustered index as well. I dont get why it happening

The query is

```
select * from orders
where cast(orders.[OrderId] as varchar(255))='7fb373a7-615d-446b-ad5c-79edf9449a7
```

Comment: The query is select * from orders where cast(orders.[OrderId] as varchar(255))='7fb373a7-615d-446b-ad5c-79edf9449a7'

Comment: I don't know SQL Server very well, but I assume the cast of the OrderId column is the problem. Can't you apply cast on the literal side instead? (Is cast actually needed at all?)

Comment: I cant apply conversion on left side because string cannot converted to unique identifier. So I have to apply this side. Is there any way I could tackle this problem

Comment: Can you please add more filters to your query? e.g. date or anything else. Just make sure cast(orders.[OrderId] as varchar(255))='7fb373a7-615d-446b-ad5c-79edf9449a7 put in you last in where Clause.

Comment: No difference after doing this @AjayGupta

Comment: Side note - tables have *rows* not records.

Comment: Thanks @Stu but I prefer _record_ over _row_, but I'm an application developer / dba, and not the other way around. _Row_ feels too arbitrary, _record_ to me feels like it is _recorded_ in history, it gives it more value and a sense of being part of something bigger. There's a good discussion here that doesn't agree with me: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/31805/75699

Answer (score 4):

You should cast the lookup value to match the type of the data on the index, otherwise an index *seek* cannot be used, a full table scan will be needed instead to evaluate the cast on the raw table data.

```
select * from orders
where orders.[OrderId] = cast('7fb373a7-615d-446b-ad5c-79edf9449a7?' as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

Or ideally use a parameterized query, either by passing in the parameter from your application runtime or using an explicit variable:

```
DECLARE @OrderId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '7fb373a7-615d-446b-ad5c-79edf9449a7?';

SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE orders.[OrderId] = @OrderId
```

Heres the big problem though, you are missing a character on your GUID, so the original error gave you the information that you really needed to follow the first time:

`Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.`

Rather than trying to work around it by converting to a string, you should have inspected the value, sometimes in these case situations it is easier to perform the reverse cast to do a quick inspection:

```
SELECT CAST(newID() as varchar(50))
```

`0612338F-7124-448B-89E2-84FB74A15172`

compare that to your original guid:

`7fb373a7-615d-446b-ad5c-79edf9449a7`

It is 1 character short!

> In the example queries above a question mark is shown in place of the missing character, replace the question mark with the correct character.

Comment: Yes thanks alot for solving my problem

Comment: I have one more question I have GUID on Id of one table and I am making left join with string column of another table and it is taking 15 seconds, table has one million records. I applied the index as well. How my problem will be solved

Comment: @NaveenKumar I suggest you make a *new* question for that. Please make sure to show your tables, indexes, and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: The poor join performance is the same as with this lookup, basically you want to join on indexable columns, don't join with a cast. Fix your other question and we can post guidance on how to work around this issue without too much effort.